# 'modelName->save' doesn't reference the name of the tabel in the database correctly in laravel

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am trying to learn laravel, and am following a bunch of tutorials

I am trying to save a object I created inside my model to my database table-contact,but when I do the   `modelObject->save`   command in tinker it replaces my table name by contacts instead of contact

Now I know about the snake case  plural name system in laravel so I explicitly rename my table in the model as follows :

```
 protected $table='contact';
```

But still I get the same error as

```
`'base table or view not found **laravel.contacts**'`
```

Here is my migration :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateContactTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contact', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('address');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('contact');
    }
}
```

My model which I create like  this:

```
php artisan make:model contact
```

The model that was created:

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class contact extends Model
{
    protected $table='contact';
}
```

## note :that    `protected $table='contact'`    was manually added by me later

Now I create object in tinker as :

```
$contact=new App\contact
    $contact->address='myaddress'
    $contact->email='myemail'
```

And then try to save the object to the database using

```
 $contact->save
```

But like I've said before laravel tries to save it to contacts instead of contact table

Also,The object    `'$contact'`    doesn't reference the default values of  timestamp and id  in the model as it does in the tutorial may be someone can hint me why..

Comment: Did you restart tinker after the change?

Comment: Have you created your database? You need to create the database first and migrations will create the tables.

Comment: @MinaYoussef yes I did and it work, also to point out I had to use ->save() instead of ->save,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what I was I doing wrong ,apparently I have to restart tinker every time I change something in the model class I create. Writing the based object again referencing the App/modelClass doesn't seem to work